# Product details page changes are not reflecting in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0

I want to reorder the product details page.

I am changing in this file `-
checkout/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` but my changes are not reflecting.

I have tried to clear the cache also and reindex command.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to clear generation file and then clear cache:

```
rm -rf ./generated/*
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Should see

```
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create **catalog_product_view.xml** like below

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Or:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Module/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

And clean cache! Goodluck!